# Switch on resistance

Tags: resistance, switching, 12v

I already spent quite some time looking at the forum's search feature, but cannot seem to find an answer. My challenge is the following, I have two batteries that are joined or separated by a switch. I would like to know with a LED if sw1 is closed or open (red line in the drawing), so switching a LED on/off infinite resistance versus 0 resistance.

After doing some research I found a comparator circuit but that seems to just work to switch based on voltage, not resistance.

Could anyone give me some pointers on what I would need to look at to make this work?

[image]

Comment: If they are similar batteries, you will have the same voltage on both sides of the switch, so there will be no difference for a comparator to detect.  You might be able to sense an open switch if one battery is being charged and the other is not.

Comment: Buy DPST switch and one of pole use for controlling led.

Comment: Could you give us some info for what purpose "two batteries are joined or separated by a switch"? This is important for devising a circuit to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use a DPST switch, a small regulator to output a stable voltage to LED, and a resistor depending on the LED's voltage drop. Capacitors according to the LDO manufacturers specification. Pick C1 and U1 from worst case scenario, that is, the highest voltage the VIN side could be subjected to.

As commented, care to be taken about the voltage difference between the two batteries.

[image: LED indicator for switch]

Comment: Look at your schematic because as drawn there is a short circuit and an unconnected input. Why a separate source when there are two batteries?

Comment: You're absolutely right, edited.

Comment: I still wonder why the voltage stabilizer is necessary. A very special LED it seems :-)

Comment: You never know :) In questioners diagram, the batteries is shown to be 12-14 V, and I guess that it could vary even more, depending on the application. With the regulator the LED will have the same brightness no matter the voltage.

Comment: It's [overly complicated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine) to use a voltage regulator and a resistor, when you could just use a current regulator instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is an academic answer. I don't think anyone would build this for a real application, too much effort.

You can superimpose a high frequency carrier using a transformer with some turns on a ferrite core on one side of the switch.

On the other side of the switch you can extract the high frequency with a second transformer. This signal is only present if the switch is closed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fexLum.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: At one time, as a student, I was going to make such a system for telephone connection over the network. Until years ago, they were used in electrical transmission.

Answer (score -1):

## Possible solution

> I have two batteries that are joined or separated by a switch.

Since it is not clear what the purpose of this connection is and how it will be used (for example, will currents be drawn, will voltages vary, etc.), I have assumed that this is a textbook problem for two completely identical batteries with a switch between them to solve which one wants some  cunning.

If the batteries will not change their voltage, the switch plays no role and its state can be indicated by a *continuity tester* (V, LED and R) connected in series to the switch. The two batteries oppositely connected in series act as a *virtual short circuit*.

### SW ON

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fODek7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**Equivalent circuit**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ4pwQ.png)</sup>

### SW OFF

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYgpDo.png)</sup>

**Equivalent circuit**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwTBf2.png)</sup>

## Basic idea

I do not claim to have solved the OP's specific problem, but thanks to it I have managed to derive an important basic circuit principle:

***We can neutralize a voltage source by connecting in series another voltage source with the same voltage but with the opposite polarity***. As a result, a *virtual ground* appears, and the network of the two sources in series behaves just as a "piece of wire".

## Applications

The schematics below illustrate the basic idea. There an op-amp produces the compensating mirror voltage.

### Zero voltage stabilizer

In the simplest op-amp circuit with negative feedback (op-amp follower with zero input voltage), nothing is connected between the op-amp output and the inverting input; they are directly connected by a "piece of wire" that can be considered as a "floating zero-voltage input source". The op-amp adjusts its output voltage Vout = 0 to reach the equilibrium.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsjefU.png)</sup>

### Battery voltage stabilizer

Here a 12 V "floating" voltage source is connected between the op-amp output and the inverting input (it can be considered as a "floating" input source). The op-amp reacts to this "disturbance" by changing its output voltage Vout in a negative direction until the difference between the two voltages (V-) becomes almost zero - Vbat - Vout = 0.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffSQXm.png)</sup>

Even if we inject a 1 mA input current by 1 V Vin and 1 kΩ R (an ammeter with 1 kΩ internal resistance), nothing changes.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDGdpO.png)</sup>

### Zener-diode voltage stabilizer

With the same success we can replace the voltage source by a Zener diode (I have used a 12 V forward-biased "ideal" diode)...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fop3wQ.png)</sup>

### Inverting integrator

... or a capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBF0JA.png)</sup>

Run *Time-Domain Simulation* to see the graphs below. The voltage across the capacitor is linearly increasing, the op-amp output is linearly decreasing and their difference at the inverting input (*virtual ground*) is zero.

[image: STEP 3.3]

Comment: What about the LED current flowing through the two main batteries? Don't you think that might cause a problem with their state of charge?

Comment: @Dave Tweed, I am not clear on the meaning of this configuration and the OP does not make it clear. It is like connecting two car batteries in parallel to increase the starting current. What is interesting here is the series and opposite connection of two voltage sources resulting in a (virtual) zero. It can also be seen in op-amp inverting circuits with a voltage source or charged capacitor in the feedback loop as one of the sources, and the op-amp output as the second source. This is what led me to propose this solution. A big problem is that OPs do not present the solved task well...

Comment: Forget about the OP's circuit. Your use of the switch does not allow the batteries to be used in parallel to drive a heavy load anyway. The point is, batteries are not ideal voltage sources. *Your* circuit is going to slowly discharge one of the batteries and (over)charge the other.

Comment: @Dave Tweed, Of course... but I have started my answer with the stipulation "If the batteries will not change their voltage". Probably, the switch should allow the batteries to be used in parallel to drive a heavy load but that is just a guess. So I took the opportunity to show another circuit trick. About charging and discharging batteries, it seems they have a high capacity; so the LED current should not affect them. But let's not argue before the OP has given some clarification on their arrangement. Then I will rework this or try to find a new solution.